# How to alphabetically sort custom posts if taxonomy is equals to 'custom_taxonomy'?

Tags: wordpress, sorting

I'm trying to sort my custom posts alphabetically without touching any of the core files of the plugin.

I've tried the code below in functions.php and it works. BUT I want it to apply only to a certain custom taxonomy and/or post type.

```
function set_custom_post_types_order($wp_query) {

  // 'orderby' value can be any column name
  $wp_query->set('orderby', 'title');

  // 'order' value can be ASC or DESC
  $wp_query->set('order', 'ASC');

}
add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'set_custom_post_types_order');
```

I've also tried adding filter through it using "get_post_type" but it doesn't sort posts anymore.
note: it goes through the filter and display test var_dump in each post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can add conditions to check if its a taxonomy ( http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags#A_Taxonomy_Page_.28and_related.29 ) and/or a specific post type ( http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_type, use your query object to get the correct ID ).